# Load other phtml file in product/view.phtml

Tags: product, layout, magento-1

I want to load an other phtml template inside the product/view.phtml file.

But my edits are not working. What am I missing?

Inside the product/view.phtml I added:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('delivery'); ?>
```

Inside the catalog.xml file I added:

```
<block type="core/template" name="delivery" as="delivery" template="catalog/product/view/delivery.phtml"/>
```

At the following section:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  <reference name="content">
```

Comment: `external html` mean phtml or html? and the design file location ?

Comment: mean phtml file. The design file location is /catalog/product/delivery.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to call `catalog/product/view/delivery.phtml` in `catalog/product/view.phtml` then you should  to call your phtml file under block `name="product.info"`  . at layout xml file catalog.xml

```
     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
<!-- add your block -->
    <block type="core/template" name="delivery" as="delivery" template="catalog/product/view/delivery.phtml"/>
    ........
```

**Also,You can try this**

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/delivery.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: I tried that, but that does not work. The block is not loaded.

Comment: please tell file extact location

Comment: The exact location of the delivery file? That is /app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/catalog/product/delivery.phtml

Comment: code semme to right... may cache issue..

Comment: Fixed!! But now I want to load the following code, but that does break down the page. <?php if(intval($_product->getFinalPrice()) < 30): ?>. I already add the following code: <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

Comment: Change block type from core/template to catalog/product_view

Comment: Also at start of phtml add $_product=$this->get Product();